# How to pass data to one parameter to a function with two parameters?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, onclick, pseudocode

Here's the cod, but how can I pass `age` to `userAge` and ignore `e`

```
function foo(e, userAge){
e.preventDefault()

}

//pseudocode
btn.onclick((age) => foo(age))
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to pass `null` or some other value as the first param, then your `age` for the second param. But, in your case, you can just pass the event along with it since it's available. You have `btn.onclick((age) => foo(age))` where `age` is the actual `event`. So...

```
function foo(e, userAge){
    e.preventDefault()
}

//pseudocode
btn.onclick((evt) => foo(evt, getAge()))
```

The missing piece of information here is *where* you get the age from. Is it attached to evt on a target element of some sort? It sounds like you might be after something more like this:

```js
function foo(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  alert(e.target.innerText);
}

//pseudocode
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = (evt) => foo(evt);
```

```html
<button id="btn">Age 21</button>
```